# python perfect square free numbers and its factors

Tags: python-3.x, factors, square-root

I want to get the numbers which are not perfect square and are the factors of the input number the problem I'm facing here is suppose we give a input of 72 so 36 is the perfect square but 12 is not, but in factors of 12 4 is a perfect square so 12 cannot be counted now I want to get the numbers who are free of perfect square and the free of perfect square factors also
so in 72 only 2,3 and 6 are perfect square free number

I am trying the approach is to find the factors then if the factors arent perfect square then its added to another list then I want to again get their factors and if there's no perfect square in it add them into another list and print it out 
I got the non perfect square factors but I am not able to find the logic of next step i.e getting their factors and eliminating who have factors as perfect square

```
def is_square(apositiveint):
    x = apositiveint // 2
    seen = set([x])
    while x * x != apositiveint:
        x = (x + (apositiveint // x)) // 2
        if x in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(x)
    return True


def print_factors(x):

    _list = []
    _list_1 = []
    _list_2 = []

    print("The factors of", x, "are:")
    for i in range(2, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            if is_square(i) == False:
                _list.append(i)
            else:
                _list_1.append(i)
    return _list


num = int(input("Enter the number"))

_list_1 = []

_list_1 = print_factors(num)

number = []

for x in range(0, len(_list_1)):
    number = print_factors(_list_1[x])
    print(number)
```

input

72

output

The factors of 72 are:
The factors of 2 are:
[2]
The factors of 3 are:
[3]
The factors of 6 are:
[2, 3, 6]
The factors of 8 are:
[2, 8]
The factors of 12 are:
[2, 3, 6, 12]
The factors of 18 are:
[2, 3, 6, 18]
The factors of 24 are:
[2, 3, 6, 8, 12, 24]
The factors of 72 are:
[2, 3, 6, 8, 12, 18, 24, 72]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tackle the same problem in a different way:

1. Write a function that computes the factors of t=the number.`factors(x)`
2. Write another fucnction that determines whether a number or its factors are perfect squares: `perfc_sqr(x)`
3. Lastly write a function that returns perfect square free factors:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   def factors(x):
       nums =  np.arange(2,x+1)
       return nums[x % nums == 0]

   def perfc_sqr(x):
       pnum = np.sqrt(factors(x))[1:]
       return any(pnum== np.array(pnum,dtype="i"))

   def perfect_square_free(x):   
       return [i for i in factors(x) if not perfc_sqr(i)]
   perfect_square_free(72)
   [2, 3, 6]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I modified my code by using `sqrt(apositiveint).is_integer()` which made my life easier for finding if its perfect square or not then I modified the complete function so that if the number is even its first made odd then tested it its square root or not now the only issue is 2 is not in the list but the count is correct

```
def is_square(apositiveint):
    if apositiveint % 2 == 0:
        apositiveint = apositiveint / 2
    if apositiveint % 2 == 0:
        return True
    return sqrt(apositiveint).is_integer()
```

I added modified this function and put it in the program

```
from math import sqrt

def is_square(apositiveint):
    if apositiveint % 2 == 0:
        apositiveint = apositiveint / 2
    if apositiveint % 2 == 0:
        return True
    return sqrt(apositiveint).is_integer()

def print_factors(x):

    _list = []
    count = 0

    print("The factors of", x, "are:")
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            if is_square(i) == False:
                _list.append(i)
                count += 1
    print(count + 1)
    return _list


num = int(input("Enter the number"))

_list_1 = []

_list_1 = print_factors(num)

number = []

for x in range(0, len(_list_1)):
    number = print_factors(_list_1[x])
    print(number)
```